# twbspagination problem in displaying next set of pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I am new to JavaScript and I face some issue in pagination. I am working on a project and I wish to display the pages in a set of 7 and it'll go to the next set when the 'Next' is clicked.
For example, 1-7, 8-14,...
It works well in the first 4 pages. [First Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghId2.png) However, when it's at page 5, the '5' is displayed in the middle and the whole thing is shifted to the left by 1. [Problem starts from page 5.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beh74.png) Also, I wish the page 8, 15,... will be at the beginning of the successive set, not at the middle.

Below is a part of the code.

Pls: I am using twbspagination plugin.

```
...
$('#page_navigation').removeData("twbs-pagination");
$('#page_navigation').twbsPagination({
totalPages: 32,
visiblePages: 7,
first: '',
last: '',
prev: 'Prev',
pageClass: 'page-item',
activeClass: 'active',
startPage: 1,
onPageClick: function(event, page){
  ...// navigate model to display images
 
  },
})
```

I greatly appreciate your kind assistance! Thank you!